# Cura slicer setting to make the printer fill the transition layer between two layer structure

Tags: ultimaker-cura

Not sure if this question is asked before, I am pretty new to 3D printing and not sure how people name this sort of problems.

So my problem is, when I have a structure that have some protruding parts on a base structure, something like this (from https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3754366):[image: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3754366]

In the slicer, between the bottom base and those "pillars", the slicer will place the outline of those "pillars", like this, directly on top of the base infill: [image: outline of pillars built on top of the "base"]

Because those lines are place on top of the infill lines rather than a solid surface, it tends to get messed up, like this: [image]

Is there a setting in Cura that can tell the slicer to build a solid surface on the top of the "base" first, and then draw those outlines on the solid surface instead of putting them down directly on the infill line? if not, any other way to address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Important information for this problem is top/bottom layer settings, which seems a bit sparse (but may be an incomplete print) as well as infill percentage. It appears that your infill is fairly low, causing the layers distress as the model continues to print.

I suggest to increase the top/bottom layer count and raise the infill percentage to twenty percent or greater.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. As stated in the question, is there a way to just let the printer to completely fill the transition layer without leaving the holes, and then build the protruding parts on a completely filled surface.